# Subtracting from current row to other previous rows in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012

I want to have the value of "ToTal Operation Income/(Loss)" by
subtracting the total value of "Other Operating Income" to "GROSS PROFIT/(LOSS)".
I don't know how to do it. The fact that "Revenue", "LESS:COST OF SALES" AND "Other Operating Income" is grouping.

Comment: You can either create page level function for that or you can get another dataset with the mathematical operation and display that value in textbox.

Comment: You probably need to edit your question and show your current report design including the grouping and then show the which values you need to base the calculation on. The expression will depend on your groupings so without seeing the design and what you have now, it will difficult to answer